# Make a sprite appear where touched and drag it around

Tags: windows-phone, cocos2d-x

Why is it so hard to drag a sprite in cocos2dx! doing this in my touchesbegan method

```
void HelloWorld::ccTouchesBegan(cocos2d::CCSet* touches, cocos2d::CCEvent* event){
    CCSprite *splash = CCSprite::spriteWithFile("splash3.png");
    CCTouch* pTouch = (CCTouch*)(touches->anyObject());
    CCPoint location = pTouch->locationInView();
    location = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(location);
    splash->setPosition(ccp(location.x,location.y));
    this->addChild(splash,5);
}


void HelloWorld::ccTouchesMoved(cocos2d::CCSet* touches, cocos2d::CCEvent* event){
    CCSprite *splash = CCSprite::spriteWithFile("splash3.png");
    CCTouch* pTouch = (CCTouch*)(touches->anyObject());
    CCPoint location = pTouch->locationInView();
    location = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(location);
    splash->setPosition(ccp(location.x,location.y));
    this->addChild(splash,5);
}
```

what am I doing wrong and whats more to be done? and is there an easier way to do this???

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a sprite only once. You can either keep a global reference or retrieve the sprite using its tag. Also, you may be calculating touch position incorrectly. Try this

```
void HelloWorld::ccTouchesBegan(cocos2d::CCSet* touches, cocos2d::CCEvent* event){
    CCSprite *splash = CCSprite::spriteWithFile("splash3.png");
    CCPoint location = getPositionFromTouches(touches, event);
    splash->setPosition(ccp(location.x,location.y));
    this->addChild(splash,5, 100);
}


void HelloWorld::ccTouchesMoved(cocos2d::CCSet* touches, cocos2d::CCEvent* event){
    CCSprite *splash = (CCSprite*) getChildByTag(100);
    CCPoint location = getPositionFromTouches(touches, event);
    splash->setPosition(ccp(location.x,location.y));
}

CCPoint HelloWorld::getPositionFromTouches(CCSet* _touches, CCEvent* event) {

    CCArray *allTouches = CCArray::create();

    CCSetIterator it;

    for( it = _touches->begin(); it != _touches->end(); it++)
    {
        allTouches->addObject((CCTouch *)*it);
    }
    //CCArray *allTouches = getAllTouchesFromSet(_touches);

    CCTouch* fingerOne = (CCTouch *)allTouches->objectAtIndex(0);
    CCPoint  pointOne = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToUI(fingerOne->getLocationInView());

    CCPoint location = _armadilloSingleton->convertToNodeSpace(pointOne);
    return location;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`spriteWithFile` is not there in `cocos2d2.0.4`.
So can you please update the code according to the latest version of `COCOCS2D`